# momentjs parse unix without converting to local time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have the following timestamp

```
1437386400
```

Which suppose to be

```
Mon, 20 Jul 2015 10:00:00 GMT
```

I'm trying to parse it with Date or moment and gives me wrong hours, always

```
Mon Jul 20 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200
```

any possible way to just parse and not convert any hours/minutes?

Comment: As far as I see the result you are expecting and the result moment.js is returning are the same. `10:00:00 GMT == 12:00:00 GMT+0200`

Comment: you can use `moment.utc()` just like @Loqman answer. You can find more about this at [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/). Please refer docs before posting any question here.

Answer (score 0):

By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.

```
moment().format();     // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00
moment.utc().format(); // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for it, you can do

```
moment.utc(date).format('X');
```

where `X` is for Unix Timestamp and if you want the milliseconds to then use `x` instead `X`

```
`moment.utc("2019-05-10").format('X')` //  1557446400
`moment.utc("2019-05-10").format('x')` //  1557446400000
```